# Angular Exception Handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have a question that i need to do in angular. I'm trying to do by seeing some examples but unable to achieve this. can anyone please help me out? here is the question: In angular, Whenever there is an angular exception, I want to print a message before the exception “There has been an error: the error is:” and a message after the exception: “Please call helpdesk”.

Comment: `$exceptionHandler` should come in handy. [Read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)

Answer (score 0):

In  fact it will depend of what you want to do :

if you want to catch error in your angular code you can used the service `$exceptionHandler` to call in your config of your module to decorate the exception :

```
angular.module('yourmodule')
  .config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$delegate',
      function($log, $delegate) {
        return function(exception, cause) {
          //do some action when an exception is raised by angular
        };
      }
    ]);
  });
```

if you want to call an API or play with promise angular embed a standard exception mechanism to handlle them :

```
$http.get(url).then(function(result){
    // some action if sucess
}).catch(function(e){
    // some action if error
});
```

Comment: thanks @jeremy-denis. I got this but to print a message before and after exception, where i need to change the code.

Comment: it's in the config part of your module (the first part of code that i shared in my sample) the function that you return is the function that will raised within the exception : you can display a message in the console but also played with angular alert popup to display a message to the user in your application

Comment: i also share with you a tutorial that allow you to go forward with this concept : http://blog.loadimpact.com/blog/exception-handling-in-an-angularjs-web-application-tutorial/

Comment: will go through it. Thanks @jeremy-denis